# How to scrape specfic tr or td from a table python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want to scrape the FirstName and the LastName of this website to use it on a automated browser input.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.getnewidentity.com/uk-identity-generator.php')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)


firstname = tree.xpath('//*[@id="reslist"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()')

lastname = tree.xpath('//*[@id="reslist"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/text()')

print ('FirstName: ', firstname)
print ('LastName: ', lastname)

input("close")
```

The website is this https://www.getnewidentity.com/uk-identity-generator.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="reslist"><thead><tr><th colspan="2" class="bg-primary">General Information</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="width:150px;">Name</td><td><b>Kamila Harmon</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gender</td><td>Female</td></tr>
<tr><td>First Name</td><td>Kamila</td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td>Harmon</td></tr>
<tr><td>Birthday</td><td>12/26/1989</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)-returns a collection of elements.
- [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)- in-built function of Python is used to remove all the leading and trailing spaces from a string.

**Ex.**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

request = requests.post('https://www.getnewidentity.com/data/uk-identity-generator.php'
                        ,data={"num":"undefine","add":"address","unique":"true"})

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content,'lxml')
td = soup.find_all("td")
data = {}
for x in range(0,len(td)-1,2):
    data[td[x].text.strip()] = td[x+1].text.strip()

print(data)
```

**O/P:**

```
{'Name': 'Jayda Key', 'Gender': 'Female', 'First Name': 'Jayda', 'Last Name': 'Key', 
'Birthday': '55', 'NINO': 'EB 29 38 84 B', 'Address': 'Flat 31l\nMartin Walk, Leoberg, S81
 0HT', 'Street Address': 'Flat 31l\nMartin Walk', 'State': 'Leoberg', 'Zip Code': 'S81 0HT',
'Phone': '+44(0)9487 957056', 'Credit Card Type': 'MasterCard', 'Credit Card Number': 
'5246585772859818', 'CVV': '899', 'Expires': '02/2022', 'Username': 'twinhero', 'Email': 
'Gamestomper@gmail.com', 'Password': 'Go7ByznZ', 'User Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; 
Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 
Safari/601.7.7', 'Height': '1.85m (6.17ft)', 'Weight': '75.22kg (158.31pounds)', 
'Blood type': 'Oâˆ’'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want first name and last name; with bs4 4.7.1+ you can use :contains to target appropriately. As already detailed in other answer, content is dynamically retrieved from post xhr

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.post('https://www.getnewidentity.com/data/uk-identity-generator.php',data={"num":"undefine","add":"address","unique":"true"})
soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
first_name = soup.select_one('td:contains("First Name") + td').text
last_name = soup.select_one('td:contains("Last Name") + td').text
full_name = soup.select_one('td:contains("Name") + td').text
print(first_name, last_name, full_name)
```